# Regular Expression: remove text before and after a statement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove text from a log-file with regular expression.

- *everything before*: `logger=`
- *everything after*: `):`

> ```
> backup.log (logger=org.brother.powerlab.database.backup): Log database backup
> upgrade.log (logger=org.brother.powerlab.database.upgrade): Log database upgrade
> clean.log (logger=org.brother.powerlab.database.clean): Log database cleanup
> speedtest.log (logger=org.brother.powerlab.database.speedtest): Log database speedtest
> statistics.log (logger=org.brother.powerlab.database.statistics): Log database statistics
> ```

This can be done with notepad++ with 2 regular expressions.

**How to do this with 2 regular expressions? Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by single regex find and replace.

- Find what: `.*(logger=.*\):).*`
- Replace with: `$1`